# A few tag-related requests for the mods

Tags: discussion, status-completed, retagging

If one of you mods is bored and feels like indulging my pedantry, please perform some or all of the the following renames, so as to get the tag names to match up with the correct spacing for the series in question.

- rename [3x3eyes](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/3x3eyes) → [3x3-eyes](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/3x3-eyes)
- rename [dacapo](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dacapo) → [da-capo](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/da-capo)
- rename [get-backers](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/get-backers) → [getbackers](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/getbackers)
- rename [yuru-yuri](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/yuru-yuri) → [yuruyuri](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/yuruyuri)
- rename [photokano](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/photokano) → [photo-kano](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/photo-kano)

Comment: Please tag these sort of request with the "feature-request" tag in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it was only 8 posts, I did this myself the hard way. Specifically, untag all the questions, wait until 3:00 UTC for the tag deletion script to run, and then add the correct tags back. As of now, all those tags should have the right names.

I've also preserved the tag wikis. I had to copy these by hand, so unfortunately they've lost their revision histories, but I think mods should still be able to access those if there's anything really important there.